# Android Details Layout Issue

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to achieve the following layout design:
[image]
I tried a few times, but I couldn't achieve it. I almost got it by using the following code.
However, I'm not good on working with layouts on Android. I only know a few about the topic.

For more information about what I got, look at: http://pasted.co/4afcaa94

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: How your layout is looking by this code?

Comment: What is the problem that u r facing? @Tarcisiofl

Comment: I cannot put the border as I want, cutting the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your layout using **Frame Layout**. Study about it how frame layout works and then try creating your layout accordingly.
Make frame layout as your parent layout

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout As parentView, circileView and confirmar button upon a linear layout . Use minus  margin to set them on the linearlayout.